# Safari extension URL

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

I want to get the base URL of the safari extension from the content page itself.
Presently, I can get the URL from the global page of the extension.
Is there any way of getting the extension URL from the content page?

Answer (score 3):

The same `safari.extension.baseURI` will get you the base URL in an [injected script](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/InjectingScripts/InjectingScripts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH6-SW1) as from the global page.